# Browserify Express App Error: Parsing file Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, browserify

I am trying to browserify a javascript file.  When I use:

```
browserify global.js -o bundle.js
```

I get:

```
Error: Parsing file C:\ocquiz\public\javascripts\global.js: Unexpected token (756:14)
at Deps.parseDeps (C:\Users\jacob\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\module-deps\index.js:510:15)
at getDeps (C:\Users\jacob\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\module-deps\index.js:438:44)
at C:\Users\jacob\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\module-deps\index.js:421:38
at ConcatStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jacob\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\concat-stream\index.js:37:43)
at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
at ConcatStream.emit (events.js:208:7)
at finishMaybe (C:\Users\jacob\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:630:14)
at endWritable (C:\Users\jacob\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:638:3)
at ConcatStream.Writable.end (C:\Users\jacob\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:594:41)
at DuplexWrapper.onend (C:\Users\jacob\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\browserify\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:577:10)
```

when I remove all Requires, e.g.

```
var R = require('ramda');
```

it creates the bundle.js.

I am not using react. I looked for other .jsx files but didn't find any.
package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
"cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
"debug": "~2.6.9",
"express": "~4.16.0",
"express-session": "^1.15.6",
"http-errors": "~1.6.2",
"jade": "~1.11.0",
"mongodb": "^3.0.5",
"monk": "^6.0.5",
"morgan": "~1.9.0",
"ramda": "^0.26.1"},
```

Comment: Can you provide global.js code?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out I had:

```
catch {}
```

instead of

```
catch(e){console.log(e)}
```

which was causing the error...